# I'm confused about concurrent MySQL connections

Tags: mysql

So, I read a book in Mysql and it says that there's a limit on how many concurrent users that can access a database.

Does that mean that If I have 20k users browsing in my web application concurrently, my web application will fail to load the data in my database? Because my web application is accessing the database every time my website loads.

Comment: Linux and Solaris as far I know can handle only 10K connections simultaneously. You need to look into balancing server, and probably you will end up using HAProxy for balancing between databases.

Comment: Even if your mysql could connect 20k simultaneously - it would not be able to process all the queries.

Comment: I agree with you, but I was just answering the question, maybe sometimes it will help someone more experienced.

Comment: i want to know how big websites handle concurrent connections like yahoo or google. just for academic purpose..

Comment: @Raymond Ho: it is a great challenge and it cannot be described in two words. Even more - it is a lot of related quests that have been solved in the process of project developing. You cannot write from the scratch the project that will be able to handle 20k simultaneous users. You have to write "something" and solve bottlenecks as soon as they appear. That is what facebook, twitter, google and other companies do.

Comment: @Pentium10: both on Linux and Solaris, it's just a matter of tuning. I've seen some linux box reach 400k concurrent connections through haproxy. *that* is quite a lot !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

20k users **loading a page at the exact same time** ? That's quite a lot -- and your webserver will probably not accept that many concurrent requests itself *(For example, Apache generally accepts only between 200 and 400 parallel requests)*.

The connection limit is the maximum number of users that can be connecter to your database **at the exact same time** -- if each page needs 100 ms to be generated, one user will only be connected for less than 100 ms.

And if you connect to your database just when you need to do your first SQL query, and disconnect immediately after your last SQL query, this can reduce the time during which your Webserver is connected to the DB.

If you have users reading content from your website, you can consider they will :

- Load a page *(maybe 100 ms on your server)*
- Do nothing but read for a couple of minutes *(which takes absolutly no resource on your server)*

As a sidenote : quite a long time before getting 20k concurrent connections *(which means about 20,000 connections per second or so !)*, you'll probably have to deal with several scaling-relating problems...

Comment: It all depends if the database queries take time or not. Some sites are so poorly designed that each hit makes one (or multiple) database queries, and slow ones. On such sites, you can easily get to the point where you almost have as many concurrent requests on the DB as there are concurrent users.

Comment: Is this related to the queries executed by the application? i.e suppose that my host supports up to 25 concurrent connection and I have only one user but the application execute about 75 MySQL queries.

Answer (score 3):

If you get a `Too many connections` error when you try to connect to the mysqld server, this means that all available connections are in use by other clients.

The number of connections permitted is controlled by the `max_connections` system variable. Its default value is 100. If you need to support more connections, you should set a larger value for this variable.

You should ask your system administrators to do these changes only when necessary.

Comment: And since MySQL comes with many preconfigured ini files, to determine which ini file you are using and need to change (in windows) right click on the MySQL service and choose properties.  The path property will tell you which ini file you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a standard web application architecture, with a database at the back and the web server(s) getting data from the database, then each instance of the web server would generally be a single database user.

From your application's standpoint, each remote user is a user, but from the database's standpoint your application is a single user.

From the web server's standpoint, the important performance number is the number of operations per second it is being asked to do.  For example, if you have a blog web site, so users will typically read for a minute between clicks, then 10,000 active users might generate a request rate of 10,000 / 60 = 166 requests per second, which would generally be well within Apache's capabilities.  (You have to consider the performance mix of your application from your web server's standpoint: CPU time, network bandwidth, disk bandwidth, memory consumption, ... to get the more complete and accurate picture of how well a web application may scale within a single web server.)

If you have enough load so that you need multiple web servers with e.g. a load balancer in front, then each web server would be a database user.  If you have scaled to the point where you need 10,000 web servers to service your customer base, you would generally have had to resort to other technologies to solve other database performance scaling problems anyway.

Comment: "From your application's standpoint, each remote user is a user, but from the database's standpoint your application is a single user." >> Very useful

Answer (score 1):

For me I think at least it is impossible since the execution/processing time are counting in Milli seconds

Answer (score 1):

after reading i found this snippet

> 20.000 concurrent users is 20.000 CONCURRENT DATABASE QUERIES... a user
>   reading a post in your site, should
>   not be counted in the concurrent user
>   number... he is logged in to your
>   site, but he is not requiring anything
>   from the database... now, if he clicks
>   in a link, the database will perform a
>   query and, then, this user should be
>   counted in the concurrent users
>   number... only if 20.000 users click
>   somewhere on your site AT THE SAME
>   TIME you will have 20.000 concurrent
>   users

Answer (score 1):

Database is very good candidate for bottle neck. If you have so big traffic on your server you should focus on downgrade number of connections to the database. Page and Data Caching can do miracle in this matter - it did in my case....