# whats the maximum number of supported concurrent threads in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

what is the maximum amount of concurrent threads that are supported in MySQL? By concurrent threads, i mean the number of concurrent queries that can run against a MySQL Database Server Instance.

I am looking for getting this value for both the Free Edition as well as the Premier Edition.

Could not find that information on the MySQL Doc. can some help me out here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980801/how-simultaneous-queries-are-handled-in-a-mysql-database

Comment: Also see this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368933/im-confused-about-concurrent-mysql-connections

Answer (score 1):

i think you should read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections . it will help you .

Comment: Thanks, I have a clarification . i saw that there was a comment for windows "Windows is limited to (open tables × 2 + open connections) < 2048 due to the Posix compatibility layer used on that platform." what does that mean ?...is 2048 the max that windows can support?